# Use temporary table in query

Tags: mysql, rdbms

Table contains multiple columns and multiple redundant rows which I don't need to work on. Let's say I selected columns and rows which I need to work on.

```
select column1, 
       column2, 
       column3 
from table 
where column1 > something 
and column2 == something;
```

Now how do I perform nested query on that selected data? I was thinking of doing something like.

```
 select column1, 
        sum(column2) from (
                           select column1, 
                                  column2, 
                                  column3 
                           from table 
                           where column1>something 
                           and column2 == something) 
group by column1;
```

And I am getting error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Subquery is excess. ```select column1, sum(column2) from table where column1 > something and column2 = something group by column1;```

Comment: You need to alias your sub query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you really need the subquery or the `column3` that you don't use in any condition , if you provide template datas and expected result would be better.

For your query to work you need an alias in the subquery, so it would be something like:

```
select t1.column1, 
        sum(t1.column2) from (
                           select column1, 
                                  column2, 
                                  column3 
                           from table 
                           where column1>something 
                           and column2 == something) as t1
group by t1.column1;
```